# TextInput inside a FlatList loses focus when off-screen

Tags: react-native, android-softkeyboard, react-native-flatlist

When a TextInput is focused and the user scrolls until the input leaves the visible frame the input gets blurred and the keyboard disappears. How do i fix this?

I am running the code in an Android Emulator. On iOS this problem doesn't occur.
If you try tapping a TextInput in the bottom of the FlatList the Keyboard immediately closes, probably because the Input is below the Keyboard once it opens. Any clue would be appreciated

Here's the code to reproduce

```
import React from 'react';
import { TextInput, FlatList } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (

        <FlatList

            data={["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t"]}
            keyExtractor={item => item}
            renderItem={({item}) => (
                <TextInput placeholder="0.0"
                    keyboardType='decimal-pad'

                    onFocus={() => {void(0)}}
                />
            )}
        />  
        );
    }
}
```

[image: Input losing focus when scrolling]

The Input should stay focused and the user should be able to type in text, even when the Input isn't visible. This makes the whole app unusable on Android

Comment: The whole purpose of flatlist is not to render most of the components off-screen. So, this is kind of expected. I would try some keyboard aware views, like react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment. That's too bad, because on iOS it works like I expected. I tried the react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view package, it doesn't help though. Guess I'll have to add the text fields to a scrollview in a for loop then

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 38):

If you use `FlatList` for rendering view without inputting data, you need to set `removeClippedSubviews={true}` or use the default option for optimizing rendering view.

For your case (render with input) you should set `removeClippedSubviews={false}` to prevent the keyboard hide/show.

```
<FlatList removeClippedSubviews={false} />
```

Comment: Finally a solution that works, thank you.

Comment: Great, it works, thank you! However, sometimes it may lead to issues with performance (https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.72/optimizing-flatlist-configuration#removeclippedsubviews)

Answer (score 3):

Ok, this is a problem that used to happen sometimes, it's a problem about the focus of the keyboard and flatlist, you can add an activity in the manifest of android

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```

Maybe not the best one but at least you can get rid of using expo.

Source: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#wsoft

Answer (score 2):

Keep the Flatlist inside a ScrollView so that on clicking the bottom text input the view is moved up and it allows the keyboard to show.

```
 <ScrollView>
    <FlatList
        data={["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t"]}
        keyExtractor={item => item}
        renderItem={({item}) => (
            <TextInput placeholder="0.0"
                keyboardType='decimal-pad'
                onFocus={() => {void(0)}}
            />
        )}
    />  
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: This is very very very sketchy and hacky, but it worked for me (only tested on android)

Comment: So we need to add keyboardAvoidingView also because it won't work for me. Please help

Answer (score 1):

using ScrollView as a parent and FlatList as a child will have a performance issue
ScrollView renders all its react child components at once, but this has a performance downside.

User KeyboardAvoidingView as parent and in FlatList add this propery removeClippedSubviews={false}

```
import React from 'react';
import { TextInput, FlatList, KeyboardAvoidingView, Platform } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView
        behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : undefined}
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
      >
        <FlatList
          data={["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t"]}
          keyExtractor={item => item}
          removeClippedSubviews={false}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <TextInput
              placeholder="0.0"
              keyboardType="decimal-pad"
              onFocus={() => {
                void 0;
              }}
            />
          )}
        />
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
  }
}
```

https://snack.expo.dev/WWSt-xZql