# Tapping a TextInput in the bottom of the FlatList the Keyboard immediately closes,

Tags: react-native, keyboard, flatlist

I am running the code in an Android Emulator. On iOS this problem doesn't occur. If you try tapping a TextInput in the bottom of the FlatList the Keyboard immediately closes, probably because the Input is below the Keyboard once it opens. Any clue would be appreciated

import React from 'react';
import { TextInput, FlatList } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
render() {
return (

```
    <FlatList

        data={["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t"]}
        keyExtractor={item => item}
        renderItem={({item}) => (
            <TextInput [placeholder="0.0"][1]


            />
        )}
    />  
    );
}
```

}

Comment: Were you able to solve it?

Comment: Seeing the same issue.  Any solutions @Joshua or @Eswaran?

Comment: @JeffPadgett I solved it by setting `removeClippedSubviews` to `false`. But I haven't really tested it in a different project to be completely sure if that's the actual fix, cause it might just be a placebo

Answer (score 5):

looks like `<FlatList removeClippedSubviews={false} />`

**removeClippedSubviews** is the key of problem and solution. Mine was true changed to false and we are good to go

[TextInput inside a Faltlist loses focus when off-screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56348262/textinput-inside-a-flatlist-loses-focus-when-off-screen?rq=1)